# WinDBG failed to show up on attaching to service process using ImageFileExecution option

Tags: debugging, windows-services, windbg

To start a service along with WinDBG, I set `"Debugger"` as `"c:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\windbg.exe"` under Image File Execution Options (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\`). But the GUI failed to show up but the WinDBG process has started properly. Should I add any other parameters?

Comment: once windbg loads, press 'g' and you should see you application.

Comment: WinDBG itself is not showing up that's the problem!

Comment: Microsoft has made it clear in the KB article, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344. Next time, pay attention to it.

Comment: @Lex Li - Yea I read that article but I don't know why it dint work well when I had given ImageFileExecution option. When I made the service as interactive, I was able to

Comment: @sarat, you did not digest every words of it. Otherwise, it does clearly mention the "interactive" part.

Comment: I'm sorry for mistake. I missed that part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the service to interactive from the DCOM Configuration Console. Now I am able to debug!